# Add and Remove Tabs from TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

Guys I have three tabs in my layout, in another activity, I have a multichoice dialog box to select the tabs that I want to be visible or not in my layout but I am not able to understand how I can remove and add tabs and fragments from my layout

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


private String[] tituloTabs = {"X","Y","Z"};



public TabAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}



@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position){
        case 0 :
            fragment = new XFragment();
                break;
        case 1 :
            fragment = new YFragment();
                break;

        case 2:
            fragment = new ZFragment();
                break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tituloTabs.length;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tituloTabs[position];
}
```

Activity Code

```
 SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.stl_tabs);
    viewPager =  findViewById(R.id.vp_pagina);
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(true,new ZoomOutPageTransformer());


    //---------------------------Configurar Sliding Tab--------------------------------------

    slidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimary));
    slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    slidingTabLayout.setBackgroundColor( ContextCompat.getColor( this, R.color.black ) );

    //-----------------------------Configurar Adapter ----------------------------------------
    TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);

    slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my problem, replaced the arrays with ArrayList and implemented the methods to add an remove Fragment and Title in this way

```
public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

public void removeitem(int position){
    mFragmentList.remove(position);

}

public void removetitle(int position){

    mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object){
    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add Tabs in Tab layout

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.stl_tabs);
tablayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"))
tablayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"))
tablayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"))
```

In TabAdapter getItem switch case

Tab1 -> case0 fragment

Tab2 -> case1 fragment

Tab3 -> case 2 fragment